# Set Display Ads when button clicked

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I have a little question here. How can I make ads show up when the button is clicked?

Okay I will explain with my `menu.class` here

```
  public class menu extends Activity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

         // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
         mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(menu.this);

        // Insert the Ad Unit ID        
         mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3502149848009990/xxxxxxxxx");

         // Create ad request.
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

         // Begin loading your interstitial.
         mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

         // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
         mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             public void onAdLoaded() {
                 // Call displayInterstitial() function
                 displayInterstitial();
            }            
       });                                

        Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);           
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                       Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aselectmenu.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                     }               
             });

         Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
         exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(menu.this);
                openDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.inflatequitapp);                

                TextView dialogTextContent = (TextView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitimage);

                Button dialogExitButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexityes);
                dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                                      
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                      finish();
                      } 
                });
                Button dialogCloseButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexitno);
                dialogCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       openDialog.dismiss();
                   }                                                                             
              });                   
              openDialog.show();
           }
        });
    } 

public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
     mInterstitialAd.show();
    }           
}
    @Override           
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
    }           

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

my question is in this line

```
 Button exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
     exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final Dialog openDialog = new Dialog(amenu.this);
            openDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            openDialog.setContentView(R.layout.inflatequitapp);                

            TextView dialogTextContent = (TextView)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.exitimage);

            Button dialogExitButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexityes);
            dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                                      
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  finish();
                  } 
            });
            Button dialogCloseButton = (Button)openDialog.findViewById(R.id.buttonexitno);
            dialogCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   openDialog.dismiss();
               }                                                                             
          });                   
          openDialog.show();
       }
    });
}
```

How to put `displayInterstitial()` method in there so when button clicked the ads will show up?

Comment: in where? which button? be specific

Comment: @NanaGhartey when exit button clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the displayInterstitial() method when before finish():

```
dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){                                      
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  displayInterstitial();
                  finish();
                  } 
            });
```

However, you should note that according to the [disallowed admob implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en):

> App load or exit
>
> Do not place interstitial ads on app load and when exiting apps as interstitials should only be placed in between pages of app content.

Failure to adhere to this policy might lead to the disabling of ad-serving to your app.

So, to stay on the safe side show the ad during a transition from one screen to the other, preferably in the play button's event handler:

```
  Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);           
  play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                       Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aselectmenu.class);
                       displayInterstitial();
                       startActivity(i);
                     }               
             });
```

Comment: oh okay i will put the display on the play button, it is fine to make it as transision right from current activity to another?  thanks for your help and the information Nana